# Pandas retrieve a value based on index

Tags: pandas

Been trying to search for this but somehow can't seem to find the right answer.

Given the following simple dataframe:

```
   country   continent    population
0    UK       Europe        111111
1   Spain     Europe        222222
2   Malaysia   Asia         333333
3    USA      America       444444
```

How can I retrieve the country value if I have a condition WHERE an index value is given? For example, If I am given an index value of 2, I should return Malaysia.

Edit: Forget to mention that the input index value comes from a variable (think of it as a user select a particular row and the selected row provide an index value variable).

Thank you.

Comment: Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - `df.loc[index,'country']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
index = 2    
print(df.iloc[index]['country'])

Malaysia
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply! Sorry I forget to mention a condition. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Check the edited answer, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Doh, silly me. It is - can't believe I spend hours searching for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.iloc[2]['country']
```

`iloc` is used for selection by position, see `pandas.DataFrame.iloc` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for further options.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply! Sorry I forget to mention a condition. Please take a look at my edit.